# OpenTK, pass array of vectors into a shader

Tags: opengl, f#, glsl, shader, opentk

So I have an array of OpenTK.Vector3 that I want to pass into a shader, but it seems that GL.Uniform3 has no overload for that. How should I go about doing this? I want to use an unsized array, and iterate over it in the shader

Frag Shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform vec4 ambient; //ambient lightining

uniform vec3[2] lightDir; //directional light direction array
uniform vec4[2] lightColor; //light color array

smooth in vec4 fragColor;

in vec3 _normal;

out vec4 outputColor;

void main(void){
  vec4 diff = vec4(0.0f);
  
  //iterates over all lights and calculate diffuse
  for(int i = 0; i < lightDir.length(); i++) {
    diff += max(dot(_normal, normalize(-lightDir[i])), 0.0f) * lightColor[i];
  } 

  outputColor = fragColor * (diff + ambient);
}
```

F# Code:

```
    let lamps = [
    {
      direction = Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)
      color = Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
    },
    {
      direction = Vector3(2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
      color = Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
    }
  ]

  let ambientLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "ambient")
  GL.Uniform4(ambientLocation, Vector4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f))

  let lightDirLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "lightDir")
  GL.Uniform3(lightDirLocation, (lamps |> List.map (fun l -> l.direction) |> List.toArray))

  let lightColorLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "lightColor")
  GL.Uniform4(lightColorLocation, (lamps |> List.map (fun l -> l.color) |> List.toArray))
```

The Editor informs me that Vector3 [] is not compatible with Vector3 or Vector3 ref
How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use this [overloaded version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/opentk.graphics.es20.gl.uniform3?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#OpenTK_Graphics_ES20_GL_Uniform3_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Single___) of `GL.Uniform3` which receives an array of `float32` (aka `single`).

In this way, you must convert the array of `Vector3` to an array of `float32`. The code could be:

```
GL.Uniform3(
    lightDirLocation,
    2,
    lamps |> Seq.map (fun l -> [ l.direction.X; l.direction.Y; l.direction.Z ]) |> Seq.concat |> Array.ofSeq
)
```

Notice the use of `Seq.xxx` to avoid intermediate lists/arrays (which consume memory).

Or you can use a more idiomatic code as below:

```
GL.Uniform3(
    lightDirLocation,
    2,
    [| for l in lamps do
        yield l.direction.X
        yield l.direction.Y
        yield l.direction.Z |]
)
```

In general, the less number of calls to `GL.Uniform` (or any function that transfers data from CPU to GPU), the better - in term of performance. Thus, whenever possible, we should collect all data into one array and issue one call to `GL.Uniform`. That would be more efficient than calling `GL.Uniform` multiple times with multiple chunks of data.

---

By the way, if most of the time you are using arrays which are transformed from `lamps` then you should declare `lamps` as array too: `lamps = [| ... |]`. So in your original code you don't have to call `List.toArray` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

A simple work around is to get the locations for the uniform variables `lightDir[0]`, `lightDir[1]`, `lightColor[0]` and `lightColor[1]` separately and to set them separately, too:

```
for i = 0 to 1 do
    let lightDirLoc = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "lightDir[" + i.ToString() + "]")
    GL.Uniform3(lightDirLoc, lamps[i].direction);

    let lightColorLoc = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "lightColor[" + i.ToString() + "]")
    GL.Uniform4(lightColorLoc, lamps[i].color);
```

Comment: yeah, but that doesn't scale well if I want to have multiple objects to be passed... unless I could do it in a loop  you think that if I did a for loop it could work?